# Did Alan Turing publish a paper called The Imitation Game (as claimed in the movie)?

Tags: history, alan-turing

I have seen a couple of Turing's papers, but never have found one called "The Imitation Game". The Imitation Game seems to be a name used by Turing to refer to his test to decide whether an intelligent entity of some sorts is machine or man (a.k.a., the Turing's test). But I haven't found any published paper with that name. So, did Turing ever publish a paper called The Imitation Game?

Comment: Though this is an interesting question, I wonder what it has to do with skeptical inquiry. Wouldn't this be better suited to any of the math, history, computer science or movie stack exchanges?

Comment: @EricLippert I am skeptical about an event depicted in a movie that is based on a true story. I am [questioning a claim made in a movie](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/864/4524). That's [on topic here](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @EricLippert If it were not on-topic here, I would suggest that it is a better fit on [History of Science & Mathematics](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/) than those that you've listed.

Comment: Was this claimed in the movie?  I don't remember that.

Comment: @endolith Yes it was. The detective asks Turing what was the name of the paper, and Turing says "The Imitation Game".

Answer (score 87, accepted):

**No** but also **yes**. In the 1950 edition of "Mind", Turing published "Computing Machinery and Intelligence" (doi: [10.1093/mind/LIX.236.433](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/mind/LIX.236.433), [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2251299?sid=21105837920053&uid=2&uid=4), [text](http://loebner.net/Prizef/TuringArticle.html), [PDF](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/471/papers/turing.pdf)) on the subject of artificial intelligence. [Wikipedia has a good overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_Machinery_and_Intelligence) of the article and its implications; however, if you refer to the article itself you will note that the first section is titled "The Imitation Game",

> **1. The Imitation Game**
>
> I propose to consider the question, "Can machines think?" This should
>   begin with definitions of the meaning of the terms "machine" and
>   "think." The definitions might be framed so as to reflect so far as
>   possible the normal use of the words, but this attitude is dangerous,
>   If the meaning of the words "machine" and "think" are to be found by
>   examining how they are commonly used it is difficult to escape the
>   conclusion that the meaning and the answer to the question, "Can
>   machines think?" is to be sought in a statistical survey such as a
>   Gallup poll. But this is absurd. Instead of attempting such a
>   definition I shall replace the question by another, which is closely
>   related to it and is expressed in relatively unambiguous words.

So while it was not the title of the paper, it was used as a section title in the paper.

Comment: This article appears to have been reprinted as "Can a Machine Think?" on pages 2099-2123 of Volume Four of *The World of Mathematics*, which was edited by James R. Newman, and published in 1956 by Simon and Schuster.  The reprint includes a bibliography.

Comment: Now you made me curious and I had to read the rest of the paper. :P